# How to do a "keys-only-query" in Google Cloud Datastore (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to do a "keys-only query" with Google Datastore API for Node.js, as exemplified in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-keys-only-query-nodejs).

I do that after having saved a number of records like this:

```
datastore.save(
  records.map(
    (record) => {
      return {
        key: datastore.key([kind, record.id]),
        data: record,
      };
    }
  )
```

The constant `kind` is a string. Each `record` has a valid unique `id` property (a number), which, as shown here, should also serve as the datastore key identifier.

The records are stored correctly. I can retrieve them all without problems through

```
datastore.runQuery(datastore.createQuery(kind))
.then( (results) => {
    // whatever...
}
```

All the saved records are returned correctly.

But when I do a "keys-only query" like this (and [as exemplified in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-keys-only-query-nodejs)):

```
const query = datastore.createQuery(kind)
  .select('__key__');
datastore.runQuery(query)
.then( (results) => {
    // whatever...
}
```

my `results[0]` return value is simply an array of empty objects like this:

```
results[0]: [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ..., {}]
```

The number of empty objects returned here is the correct number of records of the given kind. But the problem is that they are empty objects. I expected to get the datastore key for each record here.

If, on the other hand, I do a "normal" projection query, on a "normal" property (like "id" - which should be identical with the datastore key, as far as I understand, after having defined the key through `datastore.key[kind, record.id]`), I retrieve the projected "id" properties correctly thus:

```
const query = datastore.createQuery(kind)
  .select('id');
datastore.runQuery(query)
.then( (results) => {
    // whatever...
}
```

Result:

```
results[0]: [ 
  { id: 5289385927 },
  { id: 5483575687 },
  { id: 5540575111 },
  { id: 5540622279 },
  // ... and so on
]
```

So what is wrong with my "keys-only-query"? I have done it exactly in the way the documentation describes. But I get only empty results.

**NOTE:** <s>I have tested this only in Datastore emulator.</s> Same result in Datastore Emulator as in AppEngine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The objects are not **empty** but contain only datastore keys, which are stored under a symbol property: `datastore.KEY`. In javascript, symbol properties might not output by default.

You can get entity key using symbol `datastore.KEY`

```
var keys = results.map(function(res) {
     return res[datastore.KEY];
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
(I learnt that it has apparently something to do with a javascript thingy called a "Symbol", https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol. I think the datastore.KEY property is such a "Symbol", which is why it is not shown in the normal object representation. Or something like that (or totally different). Maybe I'll add some info on that when I really understand it.)