# Deleting entities from the Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, datastore

I'm having trouble deleting entities from the Google Cloud Datastore using node.js. I suspect I'm missing something really basic because this should not be hard.

I get the keys only as per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries):

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('coin').select('__key__');
```

Run the query:

```
const [keys] = await datastore.runQuery(query);
```

Delete the resulting entities by key as per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities):

```
datastore.delete(keys);
```

But I get "InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind."

If I do console.log(keys) right after running the query there is indeed an array of what appear to be key results with a valid kind:

```
 [
  {
    [Symbol(KEY)]: Key {
      namespace: undefined,
      id: '5083500323536896',
      kind: 'coin',
      path: [Getter]
    }
  },
  {
    [Symbol(KEY)]: Key {
      namespace: undefined,
      id: '5130717650485248',
      kind: 'coin',
      path: [Getter]
    }
  },
etc...
```

Is the above not the array .delete() is expecting?

Comment: Could you share the entire trace of the error?

Comment: InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind.
    at Object.keyToKeyProto (/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/build/src/entity.js:974:19)
    at /node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/build/src/request.js:194:45
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Datastore.delete (/node_modules/@google-

Comment: cloud/datastore/build/src/request.js:192:37)
    at /node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:57:28
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Datastore.wrapper (/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:42:16)
    at /app.js:103:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202426/how-to-do-a-keys-only-query-in-google-cloud-datastore-node-js) I realized the results of a keys only query are not an array of keys, but are rather an array of keys stored under a symbol property. It's obvious now when I look at the output, but it was so unexpected I didn't think of it.

So in order to run delete() on an array of keys I need to extract just the key from each result like this:

```
const justTheKeys = keys.map(function(res) {
     return res[datastore.KEY];
});
```

Then I can finally delete the entities:

```
datastore.delete(justTheKeys);
```